# Is there a repo command that deletes unknown directories and obsolete projects?

Tags: git, repo

I have some old git projects sitting on disk from a repo manifest I was using a while ago. I have run repo init and the current manifest doesn't refer to some of the directories. These old projects are now unneeded.

For example lets say right now my disk has the following in the root

```
root
|_ .repo
|_ dir_A
|_ dir_B
|_ dir_C
```

After repo init the manifest contains the following projects:

```
dir_A
dir_B
dir_X
```

So `dir_X` needs be added and `dir_C` needs to be deleted.

Is there a repo command that will detect these obsolete/unreferenced directories and delete them?

Comment: repo sync will delete obsolete projects. The message looks like this "cts: Deleting obsolete checkout." The obsolete projects should not have uncommit changes.

Comment: @Yong Perhaps depends on how those bad directories got there? I can reproduce the issue quickly, `mkdir xilinx && repo init -u https://github.com/Xilinx/yocto-manifests.git -b rel-v2022.2 && repo sync && mkdir xilinx/sources/blah && repo sync && ls -1 xilinx/sources`. Notice `blah` directory is not deleted.

Comment: xilinx/sources/blah is not a git project, and it's not managed by repo. So it will not be deleted.